# Geometry: What is the height of a solid pyramid

Tags: geometry

So the question is **OPQRS is a right pyramid whose base is a square of sides 12 cm each. Given that the the slant height of the pyramid is 15cm.** And now I need to find the Height of the pyramid.

I did my equation like this:

***QR 1/2 = 6cm
HEIGHT^2 = 6^2+12^2
                   = 180
So height is root over 180 and thus I got 13.4 cm. But the answer at the back of my book says 13.7cm. Can anyone tell me what or why my answer is wrong?***

Answer (score 1):

The correct calculation is $\sqrt{15^2-(\frac{12}{2})^2}=\sqrt{189}=13,748$

Answer (score 0):

Generalized formula, for any right pyramid having slant height $l$ & base as a regular n-gon with each side $a$, the normal height $h$ of the pyramid is given as follows
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4l^2-a^2cosec^2\frac{\pi}{n}}$$ 
Now,from the details of the problem, substituting slant height $l=15 cm\space$, each side of square base $a=12 cm$  & $n=4\space$ for a square base, we get normal height as follows
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4(15)^2-(12)^2cosec^2\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{612}=\sqrt{153}\approx12.36931688 cm$$